# Serial port doesn't work

Tags: ubuntu, usb, tty, serial-port

I have two same servers (Dell PowerEdge 1850) with Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS. I tried connect my RFID device to the one server and everything works perfect. I could see device with: `dmesg | grep tty`. But when I tried on the second server it doesn't work. On both servers is same OS and BIOS. But with `lsusb` command I can see the device is connected
 I'm new in Linux OS.

Response on "working" server

```
petscanner2@petscanner2:~$ dmesg | grep tty
[    0.000000] console [tty0] enabled
[    1.300640] 00:02: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
[   31.911685] cdc_acm 1-3.2:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
```

response on "not working" server

```
petscanner1@petscanner1:~$ sudo dmesg |grep tty
[    0.000000] console [tty0] enabled
[    1.278130] 00:02: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550A
[    1.332193] tty tty14: hash matches
```

Thank you

Lukas

**UPDATE 1**

I run command `dmesg` and got this error

```
petscanner1@petscanner1:~$ dmesg
[   90.960027] usb 1-3.2: new full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[   91.055665] usb 1-3.2: New USB device found, idVendor=04d8, idProduct=000a
[   91.055671] usb 1-3.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[   91.055676] usb 1-3.2: Product: CDC RS-232 Emulation Demo
[   91.055679] usb 1-3.2: Manufacturer: Microchip Technology Inc.
[ 1805.541979] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
[ 1805.542081] floppy: error -5 while reading block 0
[ 1818.605876] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0
[ 1818.605969] floppy: error -5 while reading block 0
```

Comment: `ttyS0`? Don't you think it is USB? First try run `dmesg -w` and plug it in and watch the output from dmesg. Then check if it registered in `/dev/serial/by-id/` or do a `ls /dev/tty*`

Comment: No `ttyS0` isn't my Device, is there always, even if I don't connect enything to the server. I tried `dmesg -w` and I see my device, but not tty*.

Comment: After I updated BIOS in worked correctly as on the first sever, but after reboot again doesn't.

Comment: Also I tried  `dmesg -c` and then connect device and run command `dmesg | grep tty`, but it doesn't return anything